# How to structure an efficient points logging system in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a points system on my blog type website, where users can earn points by contributing in different ways (commenting/ voting on posts/ voting on comments etc). How would I go about logging all points earned by a user in a MySQL database efficiently.

Currently I'm thinking of having the following fields in it's own table:

```
post_id,
giving_user_id,
receiving_user_id,
type,
date_added
```

Now, obviously if my site grows and I have 1 million ... 500 million... 1 billion rows, will this approach and structure be able to hold up without taking forever to run, providing the data types are set correctly?

I'll mostly just be inserting to the table, but want it to be able to show previous 20 (example) points award/deducted too in future, similar to the stackoverflow user stats pages.

Is there a more efficient structure that could be better for me?

**UPDATED INFO**

Yes it would be very much like stackoverflow in the functionality, one user gets one vote per postid. @Paul Gregory After a rethink removing `receiving_user_id` may be a much better idea as it will almost always be related to a post.

Comment: Perhaps if you explained what the rules on giving points are we could take a stab at answering this (e.g. do you want to do what SO here does and only allow a single vote per post? Or allow users to build a stock of points they can give out to others? or something else?)

Comment: Is it correct that for some actions, the `giving_user_id` is the system - eg an automatic 1 point for making a post, and for others it is a user? When is `receiving_user_id` different to the user associated with post_id?

Comment: @Paul Gregory ive added a little extra info to the question thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can use post_id to identify a specific comment, and you are using `type` sensibly (as a number like your other IDs), then that approach is broadly perfect for a log.

(I don't know exactly what `receiving_user_id` tells us that we don't know from `post_id` - I do hope you're not expecting it to distinguish between posts and comments).

It will not, however, be very efficient if you are going to use that table to calculate the total points each time you need it.

You should therefore store the current totals separately - against each post/comment.

As you only want to show the last 20 points, you should write something that exports the log data and removes old log entries every so often.

Answer (score 0):

Delete those fields from your POST table and create a quite similar table and create InnoDB foreign key relations:

```
id (log id)
post_id, (add relation with your post table post.id)
giving_user_id, (user id relation)
receiving_user_id, (user id relation)
type, (type as you want);
date_added (datetime or whatever);
```

In that way you will normalize your table and you will have more control of your data and logging.

Answer (score 0):

On my website I keep a point log, and basing on that I recalculate daily a summary for a given period of time. To have always current summary value, I also add the proper value to a current day/month/year sum when new entry is recorded.

About querying - with proper database indexing by date, you can achieve a decent performance even for large point logs.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would have a table called **points** which lists the amount of points that can be awarded for a certain actions.  The structure might look something like this,

```
point_id INT PRIMARY_KEY
name VARCHAR
descriptions TEXT
number_of_points INT
```

Then you can have a table called **user_points** where you can record when users performed actions that gave them points.  This table would look something like

```
point_id INT
user_id INT
date DATE
```

There could be better ways of doing it but thats what I suggest based on the information you've provided.

Hope that helps

Comment: I already have a log of what action provide what points amount etc. The second table you mention is the table I'm interested, but yours is minus the `giving_user_id` table I mentioned.

Comment: @Pattle Effectively you are elaborating on the `type` field, and then throwing away both the who-awarded-the-point and the for-what.